# NodeJS Static Files Can't Access using expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, static

I can't access my static files in Nodejs application using expressjs.I got the error
**Cannot GET /emails/invoices/invoice165.pdf**
Can anyone give me the suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: Please share your code and refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have defined the path of your static folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static('FolderName')); // FolderName could be email in your case
```